# How to decode a json string with getting the first item?

Tags: php, magento

I have some string like this `$string = {"71":"message1","72":"message2" }`
The 71 and 72 are the id's

I want to select these ide's from **$string** and pass them to some function like this:

```
$id = array('71','72')
    $collection = Mage::getModel('model/model')->load($id);
```

How can I parse the string and get the id of each one of them.

Comment: Your string is a json. Decode it and collect what you need.

Comment: `json_decode($string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a json string, so it's fairly easy to get the data out.

```
$string = '{"71":"message1","72":"message2" }';
$array = json_decode($string, TRUE); // put it into an associated array
$keys = array_keys($array); // get the keys
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$keys = array_keys(json_decode($string, TRUE));
```

Comment: it works thanks,however i want to know if i can replace the keys(the ids) with their equivalent for exemple 71 i replace it with : name1

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're looking for, and where you're getting name1.

Comment: You'll have to process that in a loop and create a new array with that information.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've messed with Magento, so I couldn't tell you. I'd suggest opening a new question with that question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $string = '{"71":"message1","72":"message2" }';
    $keys = array_keys(json_decode($string, TRUE));
    print_r($keys);
```

**output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 71 [1] => 72 )
```

**json**
The json string being decoded.

This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

**Note:**
PHP implements a superset of JSON as specified in the original » RFC 7159.
**assoc**
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

depth
User specified recursion depth

**Return Values** 
Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php